# How to fetch contents of clicked cell in a dynamic table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, flask, onclicklistener, dynamic-tables

I have tables present. Now if I click any of the below table names, like feedback, how can I get the values for them. table is dynamic. Below is code for displaying table names.

```
<table class="table  table-hover" style="margin-top: 25px;width:300px;">
  <thead>
    {% for i in tables %}
    <tr>
      <th > {{ i }} </th>
    </tr>
      {% endfor %}
  </thead>
</table>
```

Note, `i` is value of table name.

Here I want to add 2 things:

1. A click listener
2. Get the values by clicking on the tables using JavaScript

Comment: This question is quite broad. What database engine are you using? What exactly do you want to display when clicking on a table? I'd suggest you focus the question more on some specifics. If you don't know how to add click listeners, start there. Then you can tackle how to read from a database as a separate question.

Comment: i want the value for ex: if i select feedback i will get "feedbck" in a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the element clicked, you can listen for click events on the table, then use the `event.target` property to get the element that was clicked.

```
// set up the 'click' event listener
myTable.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const clickedElement = event.target;

  // now that you have the clicked element, do what you want with it
  let stuffIWant = clickedElement.<some method or property of element>;
});
```

From the example in the question, it appears that you looking for the contents of a `<th>` element. If that's the case, you can use:

```
stuffIWant = clickedElement.innerText;
```

A working example:

```js
// listen for all 'click' events within table
const tbl = document.getElementById('tbl');
tbl.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const el = event.target;
  alert(`you clicked "${el.innerText}"`);
});
```

```css
#tbl {
  background-color: #aaa;
  margin: 12px;
}
th {
  padding: 0.5rem 2rem;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
/* change cursor to hand on hover */
th:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<table id="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr><th>Feedback</th></tr>
    <tr><th>Complaint</th></tr>
    <tr><th>Praise</th></tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```